# Using R to create a collection of dataframes extracted from a large database

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, assign

Okay so I have a large collection of data I'm trying to analyze. It contains ~2 million police reports with information such as jurisdiction, type of offense, race, age, etc. My end goal is to determine the top 20 jurisdictions with the most reports, and then chart only the entries from those locations in various ways.

```
top20 <- police %>%
 group_by(JURISDICTION) %>%
 tally(sort=TRUE) %>%
 filter(row_number() <= 20)
```

I'm using this to tally up the totals in each jurisdiction and then trim down to the top 20 entries. What I'd *like* to have happen next is, using each of the entries in column one of this `top20` data.frame, create a new data frame with the name of the locality, as well as all the entries from `police` with a matching jurisdiction.

I've been experimenting with something along the lines of:

```
for (i in 1:20) {
      assign(paste(top20[i,1]),
      filter(police, JURISDICTION == top20[i,1]))
}
```

which **does** create data frames with the correct names, but the second portion isn't reading correctly and it's just creating blank data frames at the moment. Any advice on how to streamline this would be appreciated. I'm very capable of just making each frame individually, but if I can do it succinctly I'll be more satisfied.

Comment: I'd suggest `police %>% count(JURISDICTION, sort = TRUE) %>% slice(1:20) %>% left_join(police) %>% group_by(JURISDICTION) %>% tidyr::nest()` That will pull all the data for the top 20 and nest them within one table. Then you could extract them from that one object without cluttering your workspace with 20 separate data frames.

Comment: This actually worked really well, thanks! I think I got so fixated on my initial method that I didn't think of easier ways to do what I wanted haha. Making a nested collection of dataframes was much simpler.